# Apache Camel: FTP poller killed randomly

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

I created a little camel project with a ftp component polling files and writing them to a local file system.

I have the jar running in de background but recently it killed itself. Even several times a day. I already increased the log level to debug but I can't see any stacktrace or something that could indicate something went wrong.

I also increased the heap and permgem space but that wouldn't make any difference.
This is the route at the moment:

```
    onException(SchemaValidationException.class)
            .handled(true)
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR)
                    + "/errors/SchemaValidationException");

    onException(GenericFileOperationFailedException.class)
            .handled(true)
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR)
                    + "/errors/GenericFileExceptions");

    from(
            "ftp://"
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_URL)
                    + "?username="
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_USER)
                    + "&password="
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_PWD)
                    + "&disconnect=true&delete=true&exclude=((?i).*pdf$)&delay="
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_DELAY))
            .choice()
            .when(xmlPredicate)
            .to("jms:xmlQueue")
    .to("jms:archiveQueue")
            .when(imgPredicate)
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR) + "/img")
            .otherwise()
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR)
                    + "/errors/other");

    from("jms:xmlQueue").to("validator:FtpXmlValidator.xsd")
            .to("xslt://XmlToRssConverter.xsl")
            .process(rssFeedProcessor)
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR) + "/rss/");

from("jms:archiveQueue")
    .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR) + "/archive/");
```

Is there some one who could spot a issue?
Or have some advise on solving this problem?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest version 2.10

Comment: What do you mean with killed itself, the process terminated? And there is no traces of that in logs, core dumps etc? And what does the app do when the kill happens? And what OS do you use? Do the JVM run out of memory etc?

Comment: I searched the log files but nothing is logged, only once I could find 'Killed' in the log. Yes I mean the process is terminated. When it terminates it is doing nothing, that's even stranger. I'm using Debian Lenny 5.0.5. I didn't check the memory but I already increased the heap, but I'm nothing processing anything heavy, just xml file smaller then 10kb and jpg's smaller then 50kb and the app ran fine for several months before.

Comment: This is the output in the console log:
[host] Scheduler] DEBUG Queue - archiveQueue toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 119, dequeueCount: 119
[host] Scheduler] DEBUG Queue - queue://archiveQueue expiring messages done.
[eckpoint Worker] DEBUG MessageDatabase - Checkpoint started.
[eckpoint Worker] DEBUG MessageDatabase - Checkpoint done.
Killed

Nothing special no stacktrace, no exception nothing